# Accessing Variables From a Different Swift Class

Tags: swift, class

I have two swift files, each corresponding to a different view controller. I also have two classes, one for creating "Workout" objects and the other for holding these objects into an array. The workout class is a very simple class that just holds properties such as workout name, description, etc.

I am trying to access the array count of workoutList in my OverViewViewController.swift

Im a new developer and don't know how I would achieve this. Would I have to make a reference to the NewWorkoutViewController then try to grab the variable?

```
import UIKit

class OverViewViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 12
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Hello"
        return cell

    }

}

import UIKit

class NewWorkoutViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var setStepper: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var repStepper: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var workoutName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var workoutDescription: UITextField!

    var workoutList = WorkoutList().listOfWorkouts

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }

    @IBAction func stepCounter(_ sender: UIStepper) {
        if sender.tag == 1 {
            setStepper.text = "\(Int(sender.value))"
        }

        if sender.tag == 2 {
            repStepper.text = "\(Int(sender.value))"
        }
    }

    @IBAction func addToWorkoutList(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let workout = Workout(name: workoutName.text!, description: workoutDescription.text!, sets: Int(setStepper.text!)!, reps: Int(repStepper.text!)!)
        workoutList.append(workout)

        print(workoutList.count)
    }
}
```

Comment: just to clarify `overViewViewController` display all the workouts and the `NewWorkoutViewController` just create  new workout, if yes how do you present your the `NewWorkoutViewController` tapping onto a tableViewCell
 or you have a button somewhere you click onto

Comment: @Lamar I have a IBAction button in NewWorkOut.swift. basically adds all the info from the labels in my storyboard into an array. I'm trying to access this array in my OverViewViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the best way to do is create a model class name it as WorkOut with your required information. Then add the that object in array which you can define in your viewController class. Now you can pass that array information to another viewController class and can use it.

Comment: Trying to understand this correct me if I'm wrong. I already have a class that creates "Workout" objects. This class has properties such as workout name, description, reps and sets. I also have another class named "WorkoutList" which basically has a property of an empty array of Workout objects. So I just have to define this in ViewController.swift then I can use the array in all my viewController classes because they are all delegates of ViewController?

Comment: I still can't figure out how to do this. I created an object of "WorkoutList" in my ViewController.swift but I can't access it in OverViewController.swift or NewWorkoutViewController.swift

Comment: Don't you have the reference of OverViewController or NewWorkoutViewController inside your ViewController.swift??

Comment: Got it now, I feel dumb haha. I put NewWorkoutViewController instead of UIViewController in the delegates and it worked itself out. Thank you for the help!